# Binary Search Tree C delete node Some Error

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

This is my code is that

visit http://pastebin.com/697Dr51E#

when i try to build that making for me some error

> Error 1   error C2664: 'search_arc' : cannot convert parameter 1 from
>   'link []' to 'link *[]'

Function definition:

```
int search_arc(link *gr[n], char c1, char c2)
{
        int flag = 0;
        if (search_node(gr, c1) && search_node(gr, c2))
        {
                int i = 0;
                while (gr[i] == NULL || gr[i]->key != c1)i++;
                link *p = gr[i];
                while (p->key != c2&&p->next != NULL)
                        p = p->next;
                if (p->key == c2) flag = 1;
        }
        return flag;
}
```

Function call:

```
switch (m)
            {

                case(7) : {cout << "\nInput first node : "; cin >> c;
                        cout << "\nInput second node : "; cin >> k;
                        if (search_arc(gr, c, k))cout << "\nYes!";
                        else cout << "\nNo!"; break;}
                case(8) : {list_node(gr); }
            }
```

Comment: (1) Post the relevant code here. (2) give your question a more informative title. (3) There is no question in this post. (4) Did you try to understand the error msg? what do you think it says? what did you try to solve this issue? (5) Please indicate where exactly the error is.

Comment: Sorry about that this is my first stackover.

That code i try to make binary tree with search add delete and child but i make some where problem and i could't find this.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing `link *` type argument to your function  `search_arc` while it is expecting `link *[]` type argument. Change your function prototype to

```
int search_arc(link *gr, char c1, char c2)
```

if you want to pass `link *` type argument.

Answer (score 1):

This code has lots of issues. In this situation you're reusing a variable named `gr` which is a global declared near the top of the file. Then you're using the same variable name as a parameter. You should rename the global or the function argument to something different and continue from there.

It is unclear whether the code in the add_arc() function is trying to use the argument `gr` or the global `gr`, because they are different types. One is a `link**` and the other is a `link*`.

**Note** the declaration of the function add_arc() has a parameter `link gr[n]` which is of a different type from the search_arch() parameter `link *gr[n]`:

```
void add_arc(link gr[n], char c1, char c2)
{
    int i = 0;
    link *p;
    if (search_arc(gr, c1, c2))
    {
        cout << "\nExisting arc!\n";
...
```